# Change the Color of header when exporting gridview to PDf

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview, colors

I'm exporting gridview to pdf. Everything works, however, when PDF is generated the background is white and the header font color is grey. It's really hard to see. I'm trying to change the header forecolor to black before the export. It's not working.

Any suggestions?

```
  public void ExportToPDF()
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=CallDetail.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        this.GetData();
        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
        HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
        frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("width", "15%");
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "10px");
        GridView1.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
        GridView1.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
        GridView1.Style.Add("font-size", "26px");
        for (int col = 0; col < GridView1.HeaderRow.Controls.Count; col++)
        {
            TableCell tc = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[col];
            tc.Style.Add("color", "#FFFFFF");
            tc.Style.Add("background-color", "#444");
        }
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A2, 7f, 7f, 7f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();


    }
```

[image]

UPDATE*** added updated code and screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly setting the header's `ForeColor` before export doesn't really affect the headerstyle. May be an alternative is to iterate over all the header cells and set to whatever styles you need (this really works). You can try changing the below line of code

```
GridView1.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

with

```
for (int col = 0; col < GridView1.HeaderRow.Controls.Count; col++)
{
    TableCell tc = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[col];
    tc.Style.Add("color", "#FFFFFF");
    tc.Style.Add("background-color", "#444");
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I applied the following code and still the same output.

Comment: I updated my post. It now includes the latest code and screenshot.

Comment: @DennisR thanks this helps for me may i ask if how can you change the border color?

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521 you can add border color like `tc.Style.Add("border-color", "#cfdbe2");` or try something like this `tc.Style.Add("border", "1px solid #333333");`